# java outer while loop is not iterating

Tags: java, while-loop, iteration, nested-loops

I wrote the following code and the inner `for` loop works fine, but the outer loop does not iterate. Here is my code:

```
BufferedReader userfeatures = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userFeatureVectorsTest.csv"));
BufferedReader itemfeatures = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ItemFeatureVectorsTest.csv"));         

while ((Uline = userfeatures.readLine()) != null) 
{
    for (String Iline = itemfeatures.readLine(); Iline != null; Iline = itemfeatures.readLine()) 
    {           
         System.out.println(intersect(Uline, Iline).size()); 
         System.out.println(union(Uline, Iline).size());  
    }
}
userfeatures.close();
itemfeatures.close();
```

}

It finds the intersection and union of the `first line of the first file` with `every line of the 2nd file` and then it stops. However, I need to continue and repeat the same procedure for next lines of the first file. So, I think there is some problems related to my outer while loop, but I could not find what is the proble :|
Could someone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: i´d rather say that it is looping over and over and your for loop isn´t looping anymore since you already read thorugh `itemfeatures` and `itemfeatures.readLine()` returns null since you are already at the end of the file.

Comment: You could put the initialisation of `itemFeatures` inside the outer loop. Or you could read the contents of the second file once and cache the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itemfeatures has to be initialized just before for loop each time you read from userfeatures. Otherwise your itemfeatures is fully read after first while iteration

Answer (score 1):

As people stated, your **for** loop reads the second file entirely, so you have to read it again each time.

So re-create its Reader before the **for** loop, and also close it after the **for** loop.

To put it simply, each time you read one line from File 1, you have to open, read entirely, and close File 2 :

```
BufferedReader userfeatures = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userFeatureVectorsTest.csv"));


while ((Uline = userfeatures.readLine()) != null) 
{

    BufferedReader itemfeatures = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ItemFeatureVectorsTest.csv")); 

    for (String Iline = itemfeatures.readLine(); Iline != null; Iline = itemfeatures.readLine()) 
    {           
         System.out.println(intersect(Uline, Iline).size()); 
         System.out.println(union(Uline, Iline).size());  
    }

   itemfeatures.close();
}
userfeatures.close();

}
```

Comment: I just accepted the answer, but thanks a lot for the time and effort :)